# Can I use a LaTex script in Watson Conversation service Dialog flow?

Tags: json, latex, ibm-watson, watson-conversation

I am successfully using three Watson services: Conversation, TTS and STT in my application.

But I have a requirement on putting up equations in my conversation flow. Can I use LaTeX with JSON to write in my Conversation Dialog flow? Is there any other alternative for this?

Answer (score 3):

The Watson Conversation service does not explicitly handle rendering of the textual response. This should be handled by the client part of the application that is using the service to show the textual answer to the user (usually through some web page).

Now you can return parts of latex script from dialog nodes defined in the Watson Conversation service, but the rendering of these scripts will need to be handled by e.g. the JavaScript code of the application that is communicating with the REST API of the Watson Conversation service.

As for using latex scripts in JSON you can use any syntax that is compatible with the JSON - in general, you need to escape quotes `"` and backlashes `\` in the String response that will be returned in JSON.

Comment: Thanks @Michal . But is it possible for dialog flow to handle dynamically changing LaTex Script. If then how should I do that? Also now i am trying an approach where I use the Dialog flow from the Conversation service and display it as it is for some intent or render it separately at my application level if my Watson Conversations fails to understand the input.

Comment: If you know that part of your data will be dynamic - e.g. prices of items, weather information, you can handle that by sending from the Watson Conversation what should be retrieved and do this retrieval on the client side of the application. For latex you can return something like display ~equation1~ and on the client side you'll display the latex script with the ~equation1~ index. In other words the "dynamicity" will be handled on client side.

Comment: Yes you are right that application will handle the dynamic data.  What i mean is suppose a user asked "what is (a+b)^2 ?". To that my dialog flow will give the required response. Now later the user might ask "what is (4+5)^2 ?" or "what is (4.5+5.98)^2 ?" etc etc . How do I render this dynamic data. Its impossible to figure out what the user might ask and also write those many intents. The Equations at later stage can become quite advanced and complicated  too.

Comment: Dialog runtime support SpEL - Spring Expression Language -- where you can write and compute some formulas... This allows to find out the values of the expressions, but my opinion is that you would be better off computing this client side - you could parse the expression on the client and wrap it around with `<? ?>` for Watson Conversation to evaluate, but somehow this doesn't feel as the right use of SpEL in Conversation to me. :)